# On the use of 'Men' in "Why study a man, when you know Men?" - could we use "Man" instead?

Tags: word-usage

From an [article](http://www.city-journal.org/html/11_3_urbanities-how_and_how_no.html) by Theodore Dalrymple:

> It is no wonder, then, that Marx speaks only in categories: the bourgeois, the proletarian. For him, individual men are but clones, their identity with vast numbers of others being caused not by the possession of the same genes, but by that of the same relations to the economic system. Why study a man, when you know **Men**?

Could we substitute **Man** for **Men** here? This way:

> Why study a man, when you know **Man**?

I think he meant "humanity as a whole", as opposed to **a man** (an individual). I wonder why he chose to write **Men** instead of **Man**. Maybe it was to avoid the monotony of "man - Man"? I have never before encountered **Men** meaning "humanity".

P.S. 5 minutes after posting this, I had an idea occuring to me that might explain this use of a plural noun. But now I'll wait for answers.

Comment: It seems to me that (and no, it's not one of those oscillating judgements of mine) "man" is totally appropriate to use here.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. - I thought so too at first, but now I've a vague idea of why **men** could be more appropriate in expressing the author's thoughts. I'll abstain from fleshing it out yet..

Comment: I think you need the plural **Men** to accommodate the various (economic) classes of men. Why study an individual when you know everything you need to know if you know *the classes* to which he might belong?

Comment: I like TRomano's idea, but I don't think that it's directly referring to the classes, I think it's shorthand for "Men (and therefore the way they interact and the classes they create)." The relationships are an inherent part of Men as a plural, and those are what forms the classes.

Comment: Because *Men* or *men* means *all men*, as in *"The best-laid schemes o' mice an' men gang aft agley ... (often go astray)"*.

Comment: Might just be an archaic usage - I recall that Tolkien used "Men" where modern authors would use "Humans", and Lord of the Rings was published in the 1950's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It literally and functionally means *Man, in the plural*.

The word *Man*, meaning humankind, is using *man* as an individual to stand for all individuals/humans/people, even the race of humankind.

Note *Merriam Webster Unabridged Dictionary:*

> man
>
> b (1) :  the human race :  mankind :  **human beings personified as an individual** — used without an article

Also *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED):

> man
>
> 2 Also *Man*. In abstract or generic sense. Now only without article.
>
> a. The human race or species; mankind, humankind (**personified as an individual**)

Yet, sometimes we want to make it clear that *humankind* consists of more than one man, so we use *men* for this purpose.

Aa I've said elsewhere, Tigers don't eat *man*, they eat *men*.

Then there are usages such as *the best laid plans of mice and men*, where the plural obviously serves as parallel to the plural *mice*. It means the same as *of mice and man*.

The word *menkind* is attested in the *Oxford English Dictionary*, but it did not get much traction.

Comment: Hmm... I am not so confident about this answer. *Men* could just be the plural of *man*, meaning an individual (*a man*)  and then capitalized to mean the species; but it seems to work out to the same thing.